# ios swift parse.com: How to query a "like" as well ignore case-sensitive search keyword?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have 2 name fields in my class I would like to search for by using a `UISearchBar`.

What I have right now is this:

```
query.whereKey("front", hasPrefix: searchText)
```

It works fine, but I also want to search as `or` for the field "back" as well as I want to ignore case-sensitive writting.

As far as I could find it out there is no "LIKE" search within parse?
Does this mean I am limited to the `hasPrefix` function?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
func fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore(searchText: String){

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Card")

    if(searchText != ""){

        var front = PFQuery(className:"Card")
        front.whereKey("front", containsString: searchText)

        var back = PFQuery(className:"Card")
        back.whereKey("back", containsString: searchText)

        query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([front, back])
    }


    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in...
```

This works now for me!

Comment: Something like [this](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:containsString:)?

Comment: Oh! That looks great! Thanks! The only issue I have now is to "build" the OR search...

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you wanna check wether the string is in front OR in back field?

Comment: yes, that is correct!

Comment: On the [Parse Forums](https://parse.com/questions/pfquery-with-or-constraint-on-multiple-fields) this question has been asked and one of the dev's has been so kind to refer to [this](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-compound/iOS) piece of doc explaining one could accomplish an 'or' query through a compound query! I hope this will help you further! :)

Comment: Oh btw, looking at your orignal post: "Use of unresolved identifier 'back'", you define the "var back = PFQuery(className:"Card")" inside the "if". If the if is skipped since searchText != "", back will not be initialized and unknown to the program. Same goes for front!

Comment: Just saw it, too! Thanks so much again for your help!! I really appreciate your answers to my questions!